# How to download an url to a given local file

Tags: nsis

I am trying to download an .exe from a URL and have it go a folder that I want it to, not the download folder. This is what I have so far in the code:

```
Section "file" SEC07
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  SetOverwrite ifnewer
  push "http://www.URL.com/file.exe"
  call InternetExplorerAuto_OpenURL
SectionEnd
```

At this point it opens the download folder and askes if you want to run it. How do I make it so that it saves the .exe to a folder I make on the desktop??? Please Help!!

**Edit:** Thank you for the help guys, but it will not make a short cut for the exe in the file I tell it to. It keeps making a doc called E. Am I doing something wrong or am I missing a line of code in there. This is what I have.

```
Section "CleanWDF" SEC09 
    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\cleanWDF.exe" 
    SetOverwrite ifnewer 
    NSISdl::download_quiet "download.File.com/File.exe"; 
    CreateShortCut "$Desktop\NIS Edit\File.exe" "$INSTDIR\File.exe" 
SectionEnd
```

**Edit 2**:

Here is the script that I am trying to get working. If you could please tell me where I am going wrong.

```
; Script generated by the HM NIS Edit Script Wizard.

; HM NIS Edit Wizard helper defines
!define PRODUCT_NAME "Support tool"
!define PRODUCT_VERSION "3.0"
!define PRODUCT_PUBLISHER "Me"
!define PRODUCT_WEB_SITE "https://www.mywebsite.com"
!define PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppPaths\C:\Users\sgould\Desktop\NIS Edit"
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY "HKLM"

; MUI 1.67 compatible ------
!include "MUI2.nsh"

; MUI Settings
!define MUI_ABORTWARNING
!define MUI_ICON "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Icons\modern-install.ico"
!define MUI_UNICON "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Icons\modern-uninstall.ico"


!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
; Directory page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
; Instfiles page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
; Finish page
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN "$INSTDIR\C:\Users\"user"\Desktop\NIS Edit"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

; Uninstaller pages
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES

; Language files
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

; MUI end ------


!define VARIANT_TRUE -1 ;((VARIANT_BOOL)-1)
!define VT_ERROR 10
!define DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND 0x80020004
!define CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER 0x4
!define CLSID_InternetExplorer {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
!define IID_IWebBrowserApp {0002DF05-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
!define IWebBrowserApp.Navigate ->11(i,i,i,i,i)i
!define IWebBrowserApp.put_Visible ->41(&i2)i 

Function InternetExplorerAuto_OpenURL
exch $2
push $0
push $1
System::Call "ole32::CoCreateInstance( \
    g '${CLSID_InternetExplorer}', i 0, \
    i ${CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER}, \
    g '${IID_IWebBrowserApp}', *i 0 r0)"

    System::Call "$0${IWebBrowserApp.put_Visible} (${VARIANT_TRUE}).r1"

    System::Call "*(i ${VT_ERROR},i ${DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND},i)i.r1" ;VARIANT
    System::Call 'Oleaut32::SysAllocString(w "$2")i.r2'
    System::Call "$0${IWebBrowserApp.Navigate} ($2,$1,$1,$1,$1)"
    System::Free $1
    System::Call 'Oleaut32::SysFreeString(ir2)'

System::Call "$0->2()"

pop $1
pop $0
pop $2
FunctionEnd

Name "${PRODUCT_NAME} ${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
OutFile "supportTools.exe"
InstallDir "C:\Users\"user"\Desktop\NIS Edit"
InstallDirRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}" ""
ShowInstDetails show
ShowUnInstDetails show

Section "file" SEC03
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  SetOverwrite ifnewer
  push "http:"
  CreateShortCut "$Desktop\file.lnk" "$Desktop\NSI Edit\file.exe"
  call InternetExplorerAuto_OpenURL
SectionEnd


Section -Post
  WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe"
  WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}" "" "$INSTDIR\C:\Users\sgould\Desktop\NIS Edit\NIS Edit"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "DisplayName" "$(^Name)"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "UninstallString" "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "DisplayIcon" "$INSTDIR\SupportTools.exe"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "DisplayVersion" "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "URLInfoAbout" "${PRODUCT_WEB_SITE}"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "Publisher" "${PRODUCT_PUBLISHER}"
SectionEnd

; Section descriptions
!insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_BEGIN

!insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_END


Function un.onUninstSuccess
  HideWindow
  MessageBox MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OK "$(^Name) was successfully removed from your computer."
  FunctionEnd

Function un.onInit
  MessageBox MB_ICONQUESTION|MB_YESNO|MB_DEFBUTTON2 "Are you sure you want to completely remove $(^Name) and all of its components?" IDYES +2
  Abort
FunctionEnd

Section Uninstall
  Delete "$INSTDIR\${PRODUCT_NAME}.url"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\file.exe"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\file.exe"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\file-2.30-bin.zip"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\file.exe"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\file.exe"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\file.exe"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\file.exe"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\file.exe"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\file.exe"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\file.exe"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\file.exe"

  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\Support Tools\Uninstall.lnk"
  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\Support Tools\Website.lnk"


  RMDir "$INSTDIR"
  RMDir ""

  DeleteRegKey ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}"
  DeleteRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}"
  SetAutoClose true
 SectionEnd
```

Comment: Actually you do not download anything, you just ask to the web browser to navigate to the URL of a file. As it would do by clicking on a link the browser then ask you what you want to do with it. You should consider about using a plugin to download the file as suggested by Francisco.

Comment: i did try the plugin, but it is still not working the way I would like it to. It is not puting the exe's in the file that I want, it is leaving them in the download bin

Comment: `SetOutPath` is for setting the directory wher you want to put some files, it is not the path of a single file

Comment: 1) try not to top-post when you edit your question, it makes it difficult to find out how to read it. 2) there is no usage of NSISdl in the final script you posted, you seem to still use `InternetExplorerAuto_OpenURL` which won't work as you expected 3) BTW you seem to delete the same file multiple times in your `uninstall` section

Comment: That is my falt sir I psted the wrong section in there. As to the deleteing the same file multiple times, I just did not take the all out. There are just that amy files that it installs and then has to remove. But be that as it may, I got it al worked out this week end. The only thing that I have to do to it know is make it so that the check boxs are not auto checked when you run the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NSISdl Plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Builtin_NSISdl_plug-in)

`NSISdl::download "http://example.com/example.exe" "$Desktop\Your_Folder\example.exe"`

Comment: No the question is, I have not at this point really used a plugin for my script. Do I need to  make and calls or !define for the one you all just gave me, or can I just drop it in where I need it and have it work right?? Ad you are right the InternetExplorerAuto_openURL does tell it to open this page, but it also tells it to do it in I.E only and not someother browser.

Comment: Thank you for the help guys, but it will not make a short cut for the exe in the file I tell it to. It keeps making a doc called E. Am I doing something wrong or am I missing a line of code in there. This is what I have. (Section "CleanWDF" SEC09
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\cleanWDF.exe"
  SetOverwrite ifnewer
  NSISdl::download_quiet "http://download.File.com/File.exe" 
  CreateShortCut "$Desktop\NIS Edit\File.exe" "$INSTDIR\File.exe"
SectionEnd

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do here.
I am assuming you want to download a file in a folder on desktop and then create a shortcut for it on desktop. If thats right,
First you need to specify the path of folder where you want to download the file
`NSISdl::download_quiet "download.File.com/File.exe" "$Desktop\Your_Folder\File.exe"
CreateShortCut "$Desktop\File.lnk" "$Desktop\Your_Folder\File.exe"`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what is that InternetExplorerAuto_OpenURL function you're calling. I use [NSISDL](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Builtin_NSISdl_plug-in):

```
NSISdl::download "http://www.URL.com/file.exe" "C:\temp\file.exe"
```

Comment: The `InternetExplorerAuto_OpenURL` seems to be defined in an [installer for an open source project](http://sourceforge.net/p/infact/svn/244/tree//InfactNSIS/trunk/infact_with_jre_install.nsi) and just tells the browser to navigate to the given url.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues:

- `SetOutPath` is for setting the directory wher you want to put some files, it is not the path of a single file.
- the syntax for calling `NSISdl::download_quiet` is

  ```
  NSISdl::download_quiet url_of_the_file_to_get name_of_the_local_file
  ```

  in your case, something like

  ```
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  NSISdl::download_quiet "download.File.com/File.exe" "$INSTDIR\File.exe"
  ```

  in the code you posted, you seem to have only the url part
- The extension for a shortcut is `.lnk` and not `.exe` thus the call to `CreateShortcut` should be

  ```
  CreateShortCut "$Desktop\NIS Edit\File.lnk" "$INSTDIR\File.exe"
  ```

  It seems just weird to create a shortcut in a subdirectory of the desktop. Or maybe that you want to create a shortcut in the `$PROGRAMFILES` directory where the usage is to put it in a subdirectory ?

Comment: Seki, If you would like I can get you a copy of the whole script. What I am trying to do is make a utility that will download 7 .exe files from 7 urls. Have them save on the computer with no prompt so that someone could just go in to the file and run the one they want. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but it is not working for me.

Comment: If your code is not classified and still not working, put the updated version in your question to help any SO reader that would come to it. If possible simplify the script into a minimal working script that illustrate the problem by keeping only 1 section / download.

Comment: I added it to the first question that I asked sir